# Angular component siblings calling a function in service and watching it not working

Tags: angular

I have two components and one service.

In the component 1 I have a function that is called immediately on initialization.

**Component 1:**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getItems();
  }

  getItems(){
    this.mainService.getItems().subscribe(items => { //WATCH SERVICE
      this.items = items;
    });
  }
```

Now, in the service I have the function getItems() which does the job correctly:

**Main Service:**

```
public itemCategoryId = new BehaviorSubject<any>(1); //watch category  

getItems(): Observable<Item[]> { //THE MAIN FUNCTION
    return this.http.get<Item[]>(Constants.endPoint + Constants.allPins + this.itemCategoryId.value + '/1');
}

changeCategoryId(id) {
    this.itemCategoryId.next(id);
}
```

Now in the component 2 on a click I activate the function *changeCategoryId* in the service with a new number. **Which changes the itemCategoryId BehaviorSubject.**

**Component 2**

```
  changeCategory(id) {
    console.log("ADMIN Category is now: ", id);
    this.mainService.changeCategoryId(id);
  }
```

So now, after the click in Component 2, the function *getItems()* in the service has a different http get request. That new request SHOULD load up in Component 1. But it doesn't.

My question is, why isn't Component 1 getting the new items from *getItems()* function in the service even though I put subscribe to it ?

Should I call the getItems() function in Component 1 one more time or is there a different solution I am missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Your getItems functions returns a value and completes, which means subscription ends.

You should combine it with your BehaviorSubject:

```
function getItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
    return this.itemCategoryId.pipe(
        switchMap(id => this.http.get<Item[]>(Constants.endPoint + Constants.allPins + id + '/1'))
    )
}
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger things when a **BehaviorSubject** changes (next) you should also **subscribe to it**.

You are not subscribing to that Subject so the method you wanna run doesn't know about the changing state of it.

PS: Also remember to unsubscribe (this.itemCategoryId.unsubscribe()) that Subject for example inside ngOnDestroy method in order to prevent memory leaks.

Answer (score -1):

As the getItems() function in your service is an HTTP call, Angular will automatically unsubscribe on this function when it is completed (so it will not listen anymore to this). 
As it is only called in the ngOnInit function in component 1, it will only be executed on the initialization of component 1.

If you want that component 1 calls the getitems() function when you click on the button in component 2, you should consider something like this:

**component 1:**

```
private unsubscribe = new Subject();

 ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.mainService.itemCategoryId.asObservable().pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)).subscribe(id => this.getItems(id));
  }

  getItems(id: number){
    this.mainService.getItems(id).subscribe(items => {
      this.items = items;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
     this.unsubscribe.next();
     this.unsubscribe.complete();
  }
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe from the behaviorsubject when the component is destroyed (or somewhere else, depending your use case)

**service:**

```
public itemCategoryId = new BehaviorSubject<any>(1); //watch category  

getItems(id: number): Observable<Item[]> { //THE MAIN FUNCTION
    return this.http.get<Item[]>(Constants.endPoint + Constants.allPins + id + '/1');
}

changeCategoryId(id) {
    this.itemCategoryId.next(id);
}
```